# What could cause qmake not to see files included by DEPENDPATH?

Tags: qt, qmake

I have a .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../somefolder/ \
DEPENDPATH +=  $$PWD/../somefolder/ \

SOURCES  += some_file.cpp \
```

And I get an error:

```
:-1: error: No rule to make target `some_file.cpp', 
needed by `some_file.h'.  Stop.
```

But when I manually prepend the file name:

```
SOURCES  += $$PWD/../somefolder/some_file.cpp \
```

The file is found.

I looked on similar .pro files and I see that the files do not need to be prepended with path names manually. What could cause this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have extra `\` in the end of previous line. So `DEPENDPATH` line is expected to be part of previous directive. It's equivalent to:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../somefolder/ DEPENDPATH +=  $$PWD/../somefolder/
```

which obviously doesn't make any sense. Remove ending `\` from both lines.